# White Diffuse Color shows as Gray in Diffuse Color Render Pass

Tags: rendering, materials, 3d-view, render-layers, render-passes

In my current scene I have a material with a Diffuse BSDF node applied to all objects. The diffuse color is pure white. When I render the Diffuse Color pass or switch to Diffuse Color in the Viewport, the color is grey (see screenshot attached). Can anyone please tell me what is happening and how I can get the Diffuse Color to be pure white? I'm using Eevee.

Not that this should matter, but the Viewport Display of material is also white. So is the World Color and its Viewport Display Color.

Thank you!

[image: Comparing Colors in Photoshop]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The brightness of colors and how they appear in general is dependent on the *Color Management* settings. By default Blender is set to *Filmic* which has a higher dynamic range, but what you want to see is the sRGB color. Go to the *Render Properties* and set *View Transform* to *Standard*.

[image: color management]

Comment: That was it! Thank you very much, Gordon!